# Dynamically decrypting files

Tags: encryption, cipher-selection

Is it possible to store (video) files encrypted (using `AES` or similar) in the cloud and have clients' browsers download those files and dynamically decrypt them to start viewing them whilst they are streaming?

If yes, is this possible with basic `AES` or does it require a special `cipher algorithm`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you concerned about interception, DRM, content theft at the browser?

Comment: @AlainO'Dea My content is stored encrypted on a cloud storage provider that doesn't support server side encryption. My idea was to have the files stream to a browser and have them dynamically decrypted so the users could access them. It's primarily video but also text in the near future.

Comment: thanks!  I've updated my answer accordingly.  I hope it addresses your question now.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea Something I forgot to add is that the server itself isn't aware of the encryption key so the client is the only one who would be in the position to make sense of the data. This concept is something that cannot be altered because it is the foundation behind the idea.

Comment: okay interesting.  End-to-end encryption.  You could possibly do this with WebSocket or WebRTC because they allow binary transfers visible to JavaScript.  As for efficient decryption and client-side key management in JavaScript that's another interesting challenge.

Comment: I too want to encrypt mp4 video files using AES and then decrypt them either client-side or in some safe way server-side where the decrypted data couldn't possibly be accidentally leaked to cache or files that exist longer than the moment. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  You could use some proprietary DRM that does something along these lines and works with browsers, but you are probably better off decrypting on the server side and transporting the video content over TLS to protect it from interception.

To clarify based on your additional information you would have a web application server that decrypts the videos on the fly as it loads them from the cloud storage.  This should be achievable by streaming data from the cloud storage and then streaming the decrypted output over HTTPS to the browser.  Getting this to scale may be quite tricky though as you'll be held back by the latency of the cloud storage.  You may want to prefetch of cache popular segments of videos on your web application edge or go with a video-capable CDN (content distribution network) if your cost model permits that.

If you can do decryption in JavaScript and you can use WebSocket or WebRTC to send binary data streams, then you can decrypt the buffers as they arrive.  Feeding the decrypted data into a player of some sort incrementally is the next step.